# Sidekiq concurrency - How much higher can I go?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

So I am running a Sidekiq on my Ruby On Rails App and in need to process lets say 500K records. By processing, I mean fetching from remote server JSON and creating / updating some records in a MySQL database.

So right now I use concurrency of 100 and everything seems to be perfectly okay. load average is somewhere around ~2 and an average of ~14.63 mb memory usage, but you know, I still think I could go faster, perhaps I can increase concurrency?

So considering I have ~8 GB of RAM and 8 core CPU, and MySQL able to handle the load, how much higher would you recommend me to go? Or I shouldn't increase concurrency any higher?

How is recommended concurrency calculated?

Comment: There's no rule on concurrency as it is highly dependent on the environment. You have to monitor and test everything. To achieve concurrency having redis replication and mysql replication is the recommended approach. but to answer your question "it all depends"

Comment: I see, deep down I was awaiting answer like this. Still I highly appreciate it. What particularly should I monitor when increasing concurrency? Memory / CPU, anything else?

Comment: @Screatch Memory, CPU, Swap, average job processing time, various MySQL loads (queries/sec, slow query log, locks, etc.)

Comment: Both. Depending on the type of application strange things will happen in benchmarks. for mysql you want to monitor queries/sec and avg response time for query. peak throughput is not as important as consistent predictable throughput